# Aptana Studio - Placing .project In Separate Directory

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, aptana

I recently downloaded Aptana studio. However, I am having trouble with project files. In NetBeans, I was able to choose a project file location, and then the location where the files were actually stored. This allowed for a separation of project files (.project in Aptana) and the files that are actually a part of my application.

How can I do this in Aptana Studio? I can't for the life of me figure it out. Thanks! Points go to the person whose solution works. Brownie points if you can also tell me how to get a project to auto-upload via FTP while working locally, but that's not something I've really looked into yet.

Thanks! :)

**EDIT** - After more fiddling, I discovered I can link resources. However, though this is closer to what I am looking for, it's not quite the same. When I link resources, I noticed that though I can create folders, et cetera, in Aptana (under the linked project files) they do not actually appear in the filesystem where the ACTUAL files are located. I want to use Aptana as an actual file manager, but with the project files located elsewhere. Is this not possible?

**EDIT** - More fiddling has taught me that I can link the resources by setting a connection whose destination folder is where the actual files are located. This is even closer to what I want, but it's sloppy--I have to expand three levels of folders to simply access my files. Though someone could make the argument that this is a minor issue, it's quite annoying. Any solutions?